# On some servers, my users have to use <username>@<domainname> to login and on other servers they have to use the domainname\username ormat

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server-2016

On some servers, my users have to use `username@domainname` to login and on other servers they have to use the `domainname\username` format. All the servers are in the same domain, and running Windows 2012 and 2016. The wrong format gives error *Incorrect credentials*.

Has anybody seen this behavior before?
Does anybody know what might be causing it?

Comment: What operating systems?

Comment: Windows 2012 and 2016

Comment: Strange. Do they get a error message if they attempt the wrong format? Does the users have a UPN defined?

Comment: if they use the wrong format, error is just "incorrect credentials"